# Excel Chart Range from Concatenate value

Tags: excel, charts

I need control the Excel's chart range by using Concatenated values... or some other way.
I've tried using the formula seen in the figure below in the Chart range. But I get an error.

I need to tell how many rows to use, from the first value.

Is this possible somehow?

[image]

Comment: How about `=INDIRECT(your formula)`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that initially. But it didn't work. Maybe I'll give it another try.

Comment: I receive an error: "That function isn't valid". But I know it works in the sheet since it displays the corresponding value.

Comment: What I've found: https://trumpexcel.com/dynamic-chart-range/

Comment: This seems to work if I don't add any data to the table below where I want to plot. But in my case I'll always have some values, zeros, NaN's e.t.c.